# How to integrate google plus api with laravel 5.1

Tags: php, forms, laravel, authentication

Hello I am a fresh new Laravel Framework, so I want to create login with Google Plus account. How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

Here complete library for login with Google+ in Laravel :https://github.com/TheMonkeys/laravel-google-auth